# Can not add Button with grid to list in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to arrange buttons like this with tkinter:
[image: Screenshot]

This works with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

btn = []

def btnClicked (btnNum):
    print(btnNum)

b=0
for a in range(9):
    if(a%3 == False):
        b = b+1
    btn.append(Button(root, text="", command = lambda c=a: btnClicked(c), height = 10, width = 20).grid(row = a-3*(b-1), column=b))

root.mainloop()
```

However in order to perform an action on these buttons, I need to pack them, like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

btn = []

def btnClicked (btnNum):
    print(btnNum)
    btn[btnNum]["text"] = "X"

b=0
for a in range(9):
    if(a%3 == False):
        b = b+1
    btn.append(Button(root, text="", command = lambda c=a: btnClicked(c), height = 10, width = 20).grid(row = a-3*(b-1), column=b))
    btn[a].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'

While this code works, as I would like it when I do not arrange the buttons in a grid, like that:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

btn = []

def btnClicked (btnNum):
    print(btnNum)
    btn[btnNum]["text"] = "X"

b=0
for a in range(9):
    if(a%3 == False):
        b = b+1
    btn.append(Button(root, text="", command = lambda c=a: btnClicked(c), height = 10, width = 20))
    btn[a].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How can I get rid of the error in my second code example or align the buttons in a grid in the third example respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the problems with your code and their solutions.

1. You don't need to use two variables *a* and *b*. You can do it with just one using **modulus** (a//3) and **remainder** (a%3).
2. If you ever print out the `btn` list, you will realize the problem straightaway. It consists of `None`'s only because you are appending after performing the `grid` operation on the buttons, which returns `None`. You need to first append the widget and then "grid" it.

So, here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

btn = []

def btnClicked(btnNum):
    print(btnNum)
    btn[btnNum]["text"] = "X"

for a in range(9):
    btn.append(Button(root, text="", command = lambda c=a: btnClicked(c), height = 10, width = 20))
    btn[-1].grid(row = a%3, column=a//3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]